# Efficient Device Detection in Next.js with Centralized Logic

Tags: next.js

I'm using Next.js page routing and needed to detect the user's device both on the client and server sides, as my pages are served from the server.
I'm checking the `req` headers on the server. I found myself duplicating code in every page file to detect if the user is on a mobile device and then passing this information as a prop.
Additionally, I was setting this mobile device information in the context within `_app.tsx` to make it available to all components.
Is there a cleaner way to handle this?